# NSRunLoop for showing UIAlertView when iPad is in sleep mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nstimer

I have a weird situation, On an button click event i add timer to NSRunLoop which should fire after 'x' minutes. But if iPad goes to sleep before 'x' minutes and that timer value is reached its 'x' value and when after that i again open my app it does not show an alert.

So if timer time is up and iPad is in sleep mode it should show an alert after i start again the app. Below is my code.

```
 NSTimer *uiTimer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:[x intValue] * 60 target:self selector:@selector(fireTheMethod:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
 [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:uiTimer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];

-(void) fireTheMethod
{
  UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
  [alert show];
}
```

Comment: i think you should go with local notification, instead of showing a alert.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could change your logic a little bit? In your app's `applicationDidEnterBackground:`, you could invalidate your timer, and save the current time. Then in `applicationWillEnterForeground:`, you could get the current time, and if the time difference is greater than the required interval, display the alert.